# XAML is spell check Enabled is not working

Tags: xaml

I created small app in XAML. I am getting problem, i enabled 
IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"

IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"
 but still this option is not working.when i put wrong word it doesn't predict nor check word.

Comment: Post your XAML. Also, are you using Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: yes.<TextBox x:Name="JobTitle"
                     IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"
                     IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"
                     Width="200"
                     Height="40"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Margin="5"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

Answer (score 0):

`IsTextPredictionEnabled` is used for the autocomplete features only. Check this documentation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209690 it states that this feature is for `TextBox` to determine whether to provide autocomplete feature or not. It, in any way, doesnot check your word spells.

To do the word spell check, please read the documentation about `SpellCheck` class on MSDN at, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx

You can also get the sample code from MSDN (look at the last section in the document).